# How prevent script re-execution on jqueryui dialog creation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a DIV with some contents and scripts inside, which are executed on document rendering (everything is OK). But when I create a new jQueryUI dialog, based on this DIV, all scripts are executed again.
Dialog is created by script, like this:

```
$('#createDoc').dialog({
    closeOnEscape: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Some title'
});
```

Is there any way to prevent script execution in this case? I can't place these scripts in HEAD or move to another place in document.

Using jQuery 1.7.1 and jQueryUI 1.10.3.

With jQuery 2.0.2 everything works fine, but I need to use older version.

Comment: I don't know that those two versions of code are compatible. I would either upgrade jQuery to 1.9.1, or downgrade jQUI to 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that

```
$('#createDoc').dialog({
    closeOnEscape: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Some title'
    open: function( event, ui ) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading to jQuery 1.9.1.